# Listing device in /dev/ path

Tags: udev, devices, serial-port

I have been trying for several days to get my ESP32 to show in /dev/ttyUSB*

I cannot get it to show at all

I am running ubuntu

If I do lsusb I get

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a86:55d4 QinHeng Electronics USB Single Serial
```

If I run :

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUS*
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUS*': No such file or directory

sudo dmesg
[ 2453.003616] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2453.112386] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=55d4, bcdDevice= 4.43
[ 2453.112403] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2453.112410] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB Single Serial
[ 2453.112416] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: [removed by me]
```

What am I doing wrong? At one point I ran an ls /dev/* and by elimination i found that the device is

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May  7 20:07 189:5 -> ../bus/usb/001/006
```

**EDIT**

```
 ubuntu@raspberrypi:~$ usb-devices | awk '/55d4/' RS=
 T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  8 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
 D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=02(commc) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
 P:  Vendor=1a86 ProdID=55d4 Rev=04.43
 S:  Product=USB Single Serial
 S:  SerialNumber= Same as the one before
 C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=134mA
 I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
 I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

I am running :

```
 Welcome to Ubuntu 21.10 (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-1025-raspi aarch64)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/55d4/' RS=`. And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: thanks for your help. i have made the changes above.

Comment: This device isn't supported by the kernel. You'll need to find a driver for it.

Comment: You are right, at the end it boiled down to a missing driver. If you want, add the answer so you get the rep. I will edit your answer with specific details.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, feel free to write your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a driver issue as correctly pointed out by @Pilot6.

For those who might experience this sort of issue in the future:

[Have a look at your ESP32](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmDxP4O4Trk), one of the chips should have something written on it that can help you look up the chip driver

For example, mine was C9102X, which I got from [here](https://github.com/WCHSoftGroup/ch343ser_linux).